# Does all iOS devices has Apple Wallet application available on a device?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, applet

I am currently working under an application integrated with Apple Wallet. I am curious, should I check existing Apple Wallet application on a device? As I know, it's default application, user can not remove it from a device. So my final question is - Does all iOS devices like iPhones and iPads running at least iOS 11.0 has Apple Wallet available on a device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to add a pass, you can check the availability of Wallet passes with this method:

```swift
PKPassLibrary.isPassLibraryAvailable()
```

More infos here: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpasslibrary/1617080-ispasslibraryavailable

Answer (score 0):

The answer is true. Since iOS 10, user can delete many system app but the Wallet app cannot be deleted by user (except iOS device has been root)